# Way to save jList data into a txt file?

Tags: java, jtextfield, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am looking for a way to save the users input from a jlist into a txt file. It's for a homework project. I have the program set up to take user input from a textfield, then it goes into the jlist once they hit the add button. The jlist has a defaultlistmodel on it, and I'm wondering if there is a way to create a save button and allow it to save the complete jlist into a .txt file.

Also, here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class i extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField jTextField;
DefaultListModel ListModel = new DefaultListModel();
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList <String>();
String str;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                i frame = new i();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public i() {
    super("List");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    jTextField = new JTextField();
    jTextField.setBounds(15, 80, 168, 20);
    contentPane.add(jTextField);
    jTextField.setColumns(10);

    final JList jList = new JList(ListModel);
    jList.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    jList.setBounds(289, 54, 135, 197);
    contentPane.add(jList);


    JButton jButton = new JButton("Add");
    jButton.setBounds(190, 79, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(jButton);
    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String str=jTextField.getText();
            ListModel.addElement(str);
            jTextField.setText("");
            arr.add(str);
            System.out.println(arr);
        }
    });



    JButton delete = new JButton("DELETE");
    delete.setBounds(190, 162, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(delete);
    delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent k){
            ListModel.removeElement(jList.getSelectedValue());

        }
    });

    JButton btnUp = new JButton("UP");
    btnUp.setBounds(190, 125, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnUp);
    btnUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int index = jList.getSelectedIndex();
            if(index == -1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select something to move.");
            } else if(index > 0) {
                String temp = (String)ListModel.remove(index);
                ListModel.add(index - 1, temp);
                jList.setSelectedIndex(index -1);
            }
        }
    });

    JButton btnDown = new JButton("DOWN");
    btnDown.setBounds(190, 196, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnDown);
    btnDown.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){ 
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){ 
            int index = jList.getSelectedIndex(); 
            if( index == -1 ) 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select something to move."); 
            else if( index < ListModel.size() - 1 ){ 
                String temp = (String)ListModel.remove( index ); 
                ListModel.add( index + 1, temp ); 
                jList.setSelectedIndex( index + 1 ); 
            } 
        } 
    }); 

    JLabel lblItems = new JLabel("Items:");
    lblItems.setBounds(290, 37, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblItems);

    JButton btnPrint = new JButton("PRINT");
    btnPrint.setBounds(190, 228, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnPrint);
    btnPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: This question is way too broad. Which part of this is giving you trouble? Creating the button? Adding an ActionListener to the button? Getting the data from the JList? Saving data to a text file? Something else? What have you tried so far? Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I apologize, I am having trouble figuring out how to get the data from the jlist and getting it into a text file. I have looked at other websites and other questions and have had no luck.

Comment: Break your problem down into smaller steps. Can you write a standalone program that writes some hard-coded Strings to a file? Can you write a different standalone program that prints to the console the contents of the JList? When you have both programs working separately, then you can think about combining them. You'll have better luck posting about a specific step than posting about your whole goal.

Comment: You could use a `PrintWriter(File arg0)`

Answer (score 0):

you need use File class to save your list in that

```
File file = new File("c:/test/myfile.txt");
```

now file's created and opened!
and for write some output to file

use Formatter Class:

```
public class CreateFile
{
   private Formatter x;
    void openFile()
    {
    try
    {
        x = new Formatter("c:/myfile.txt");
        System.out.println("you created a file");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("error in opening file");
    }
    }
    void addFile()
    {
        x.format("%s %s %s\n","20","Start","Today");
    }
    void closeFile()
    {
        x.close();
    }
}
```

as you see,addFile method accept 3 String passed to write in the file
i passed "20" , "Start" , "Today" 
you can use more/less than %s , and pass user input or a list in String to write in the file.
good luck