# Deleting object data from file?

Tags: java, file, jlist

I have a JList with contacts i have added (from a txt file)      "first name   last name"

I am able to delete a row from the JList but it's not removed from the file. Whenever I rerun the project, "the deleted from jlist" element reappears (bcz its still in the txt file)

My question is how can I delete this element from the file also ??

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're not persisting back to the file at all. If you want your changes to the JList to be reflected in the file, you'll need to update it. If it works for you, the easiest way is likely to create a save method that overwrites the text file with the current JList.
If you're not sure how to do that, this might help: [Way to save jList data into a txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642415/way-to-save-jlist-data-into-a-txt-file)